# python help loop for to create dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

Hi everyone I have such a data structure from CSV file.
I would like to create a dictionary divided by place that contained the various dates referring to that day.

```
DATA        | LUOGO     | CAP       | KEY
05/05/12    LUOGO1       05254        545122
05/05/12    LUOGO2       05554        545745
05/05/12    LUOGO3       05444        555544
05/05/12    LUOGO4       05774        777888
05/05/12    LUOGO5       05854        542225

06/05/12    LUOGO1       05554        585547
06/05/12    LUOGO2       07854        545888
06/05/12    LUOGO3       04544        585858
06/05/12    LUOGO4       05778        789585
06/05/12    LUOGO5       05785        525477
```

I'd get something like that with a for loop,
I've been banging my head on it for days but I can't find a solution that I guess is trivial

```
luoghi = { 'LUOGO1': 
                    {'05/05/12': {'data': '05/05/12', 'LUOGO': 'LUOGO1', 'CAP': '05254', 'KEY': '545122'},
                    '06/05/12': {'data': '06/05/12', 'LUOGO': 'LUOGO1', 'CAP': '05554', 'KEY': '585547'}},
           'LUOGO2': {'05/05/12': {'data': '05/05/12', 'LUOGO': 'LUOGO2', 'CAP': '05554', 'KEY': '545745'},
                      '06/05/12': {'data': '06/05/12', 'LUOGO': 'LUOGO2', 'CAP': '07854', 'KEY': '545888'}}
        }


print(luoghi['LUOGO1']['05/05/12'])
```

Result:

```
{'data': '05/05/12', 'LUOGO': 'LUOGO1', 'CAP': '05254', 'KEY': '545122'}
```

Can anyone tell me how with a FOR loop I can get it?

Thank you very much

Comment: You should first show what you tried, but other than that, the output structure has a lot of redundant data, are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: Just to clarify your problem. You want to read the csv and loop through it line by line, then get a `luoghi` dictionary you described in your question, right?
Also can you please specify what is a the delimiter used in the csv file? (tab, spaces, pipe, etc.?)

Answer (score 0):

here your code

```
luoghi = { 'LUOGO1': 
                    {'05/05/12': {'data': '05/05/12', 'LUOGO': 'LUOGO1', 'CAP': '05254', 'KEY': '545122'},
                    '06/05/12': {'data': '06/05/12', 'LUOGO': 'LUOGO1', 'CAP': '05554', 'KEY': '585547'}},
           'LUOGO2': {'05/05/12': {'data': '05/05/12', 'LUOGO': 'LUOGO2', 'CAP': '05554', 'KEY': '545745'},
                      '06/05/12': {'data': '06/05/12', 'LUOGO': 'LUOGO2', 'CAP': '07854', 'KEY': '545888'}}
        }
```

```
for  key,value in luoghi.items():
    for key2,value2 in value.items():
        print(value2)
```

if you need output as list type here is your another code

```
print([val2 for key,val in luoghi.items() for key2,val2 in val.items()])
```

Answer (score 0):

Does something like that does the trick ?

```py
import re

luoghi = {}
with open("test.csv", "r") as f:
    # Skip the first line
    f.readline()

    # Iterate on other lines
    for line in f:
        if line.strip() != "":
            data, luogo, cap, key = re.split("\s+", line.strip())

            # new luogo ?
            if not luogo in luoghi.keys():
                luoghi[luogo] = {}
            
            # new data for luogo ?
            if not data in luoghi[luogo].keys():
                luoghi[luogo][data] = {}

            # Push data
            luoghi[luogo][data] = {
                'data'  : data,
                'LUOGO' : luogo,
                'CAP'   : cap,
                'KEY'   : key
            }
```

With your data being saved in the `test.csv` file of course.

Comment: `LUOGO1`, `LUOGO2`, etc. being obvious placeholders, I'm pretty sure that real data will have spaces in there (I happen to know that "luogo" means "place" or "city"), so this code would fail for "San Francisco" for example. Also how about escaped characters? Much better to rely on the `csv` module when reading a csv

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```py
luoghi = {}
with open("path/to/luoghi.csv", "r") as csv_file:
    _ = csv_file.readline()  # first line is only the header, we don't care about
    for csv_line in csv_file.readlines():
        stripped_line = csv_line.strip()
        if not len(stripped_line):
            # in case of an empty line
            continue
        data, luogo, cap, key = [
            field for field in stripped_line.split(" ") if len(field)
        ]

        if luogo not in luoghi:
            luoghi[luogo] = {}

        luoghi[luogo][data] = {"data": data, "LUOGO": luogo, "CAP": cap, "KEY": key}
```

You can delete the empty line check if non-existence of empty lines are guaranteed in the csv.

Answer (score 0):

I mis expressed myself. the structure I put in was just an example of the file.
the CSV file is online and the code used to open it is as follows.

```
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pcm-dpc/COVID-19/master/dati-regioni/dpc-covid19-ita-regioni.csv"
r = requests.get(url)
buff = io.StringIO(r.text)
filecsv = csv.DictReader(buff)
```

I would like to create a split dictionary called PLACES where for each region (Abruzzo, Basilicata etc.) corresponds a date (2020-02-24T18:00:00, 2020-02-25T18:00:00) and at each date the row corresponds with all the other data.

I would like you to then write

```
print(luoghi['Abruzzo']['2020-09-05T17:00:00'])
```

the result corresponds to

```
{'data': '2020-09-05T17:00:00', 'stato': 'ITA', 'codice_regione': '13', 'denominazione_regione': 'Abruzzo', 'lat': '42.35122196', 'long': '13.39843823', 'ricoverati_con_sintomi': '32', 'terapia_intensiva': '2', 'totale_ospedalizzati': '34', 'isolamento_domiciliare': '449', 'totale_positivi': '483', 'variazione_totale_positivi': '12', 'nuovi_positivi': '13', 'dimessi_guariti': '2910', 'deceduti': '472', 'casi_da_sospetto_diagnostico': '3396', 'casi_da_screening': '469', 'totale_casi': '3865', 'tamponi': 
'164140', 'casi_testati': '106544', 'note': 'Dal totale dei positivi è stato sottratto 1 caso precedentemente conteggiato 2 volte'}
```

Comment: I have tried various cycles. but the last entry is always overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data=pd.read_csv('data/Tect.csv')

data2=data.set_index(['LUOGO','DATA'])
key1=data['LUOGO'].unique()
key2= data['DATA'].unique()

data_dict=dict()
for k1 in key1:
    new_dict=dict()
    for k2 in key2:
        new_dict[k2]=list(data2.loc[k1,k2])
    data_dict[k1]=new_dict
data_dict['LUOGO1']['05/05/12']
```